# How to center an image within a div

Tags: css, wordpress, html, header, center

I'm attempting to center the logo within my header. I tried the `display:block` and `margin:auto` within my `#site-title` class, but it isn't working.

The link to the code is: http://pastebin.com/iNvhTSBL
And the CSS is: http://pastebin.com/f5mPTjuU

I'm not sure what to do...maybe I'm not doing the CSS correctly?

Any help would be appreciated! The CSS was from a wordpress theme, just letting you all know.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next time, post only the relevant code bits in your question.  That makes it MUCH more likely people will bother to answer.

If this is the code you are referring to:

```
<div id="header">
            <div id="site-title">
                    <a href="http://www.panduzee.com/wordpress"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ysxPP.jpg"></a>
            </div>
            <!-- other bits stripped for brevity -->
            <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
```

and the css is this:

```
#header {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dedfe0; 
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
#site-title { 
    float: left; 
    width: 100%; 
    padding-right: 40px; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    line-height: 27px; 
    font-size: 23px; 
    display:block; 
    margin: auto;
}  
#site-title a {
    color: #333; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    text-decoration: none; 
}
```

Then you need to revise the css as follows:
1. remove the `float: left` from the site-title.  Unecessary.
2. Note that your `padding-right of 40px` is going to cause problems with your `width: 100%`
3.  Add `text-align: center;` to the site-title.
4.  Add `margin: 0 auto;` to your site-title a

The following code will do what you want:

```
#header {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dedfe0; 
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
#site-title { 
    width: auto; 
    padding-right: 40px; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    line-height: 27px; 
    font-size: 23px;  
    text-align: center;
}  
#site-title a {
    color: #333; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to `#site-title`

```
text-align: center;
```

Comment: You could also use #site-title img { display: block; margin: 0 auto; }. http://dorward.me.uk/www/centre/

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
#header {
width: 500px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
</style>
<div id="header">
<!-- div content here -->
</div>
```